# how to find what is currently in the callback queue in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, profiler, event-loop

I'm looking at some code that uses setInterval to call a function every 30 seconds, but it doesn't look like it's firing every 30 seconds, in fact it fires every 3 minutes roughly. I think it's because there are other functions enqueued and it takes a while to get to call this function. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there any way to check what's there on the callback queue either visually or even something simple to dump every 1 sec to some log file?

Comment: Whoever -1'd question could you please explain why? I'm happy to make any changes to the question if you could give reason...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `process._getActiveHandles()` and `process._getActiveRequests()`

See  [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nodejs/ztspFn-BKgE/qw1I9VLSG_gJ) in `node.js` mailing list.

**update:** there is a good package for this - https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to check that it is called e.g. every 30 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() { console.log(new Date());}, 30000);
```

Comment: I'm not worried about whether the function I'm looking at is called, rather I'm interested to know what are the other functions in the queue which results in the lag.